# How to initialise a Managed Bean in request scope from a servlet

Tags: jsf, servlets, managed-bean

I have a servlet that will navigate to a JSF page upon some conditions using ExternalContext.redirect.
I need to initialise a Managed Bean in this Servlet and set it in request scope so that my JSF page can directly access the Managed Bean's property and display them on the page load.

I had seen posts that sets the bean using getServletContext()

Like,

```
getServletContext().setAttribute("beanName",new Bean())
```

it works.But this approach will be setting the bean in application scope instead of request scope.

Also i tried the following:

```
request.setAttribute("beanName",new Bean())
```

it doesnt work

So pls let me know if there is any way to set /initialise a managed bean in a request scope

Comment: This is a strange requirement. Why don't you simply use a bean with `@RequestScope` and access it from your page?

Comment: Create a managed bean with `@ViewScoped` annotation. The bean will be created since user access to the view (this will be in the redirection) and will live until the user leaves the view (change to another view, closes the tab or closes the browser).

Comment: Are you in a servlet or a backing bean?

Comment: My requirement is i am  navigating from a Non-JSF resource like a servlet to a JSF page.Doing so i need to have my managed bean preloaded with some values IN REQUEST SCOPE so that the page i am rendering can pull these values and display.
@LaurentG I am using JSF 1.2 -No Annotations.My requirement does'nt bothers about how it is configured in JSF, as i am navigating from Servlet (A non JSF-Resource) to a JSF Page ( I am using XHTML: FYI)

Comment: @SazzadurRahaman I am Using Servlet=>JSF Page navigation.SO no backing Beans here.

Comment: This makes really no sense. What's the concrete functional requirement? What's the role of that servlet?

Comment: Requirement is:JSP to JSF Navigation.WHile Navigating i must bring in some business commands to fetch some data and display it in the JSF Page.Its a Pretty Senseless requirement to combine JSP and JSF in the same app,et the JSP pages will be decommission in a year.
JSP=>Servlet =>Servlet calls a Managed Bean's business process.(Getting managed bean by FacesContext thro Lifecycle factory methods)..Now Servlet Navigates the Control to the JSF with a Newly Created Bean,This bean shud b in request scope for the JSF page to display

Comment: Why don't you just do servlet's job in constructor of the backing bean and then link directly to the JSF page?

Comment: Thats a pretty good idea..bt 
I have to see if this Bean is resued across the App.
Also to check if the value population through the constructor wud have impact on any other module where this bean is used.
Is there any other way ???

Answer (score 0):

If it's a request scoped bean, use `HttpServletRequest#setAttribute()`

`BeanName beanName = new BeanName();`

`request.setAttribute("beanName", beanName);`

If its a session scoped bean,

`request.getSession().setAttribute("beanName", beanName);`

Comment: Thanks for ur reply! But i had tried them already.Dint work.And i wanted the bean to be in REQUEST SCOPE

Comment: @SaiPrasadSabeson Have you made an entry for the bean in `faces-config.xml` ?

Comment: Yes I have made....Since we are having no JSF Lifecycle in a Servlet ,i guess using faces-config for our discussion is just out of box

Comment: Vikas, OP is sending a redirect from servlet to JSF page. You should know that a redirect creates a **new** HTTP request.

Comment: @BalusC Great ! Agreed..so thats why my request scope isnt working...
is there any other way that this new request con hold my bean ?